# Ubuntu 20.04; Some repeat keys are "overshooting"

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, delete, numlock, numpad

So I've just set up Ubuntu 20.04 on a new laptop (HP Envy 2022, i7-1260P) and I've noticed a strange phenomenon with repeat keys.

If I'm typing and want to repeat the letter "h", I hold down the "h" key and the keypress gets repeated, and stops repeating when I release the "h" key. Good, that works as expected.

However, if I'm holding the "Delete" key, the keypress repeats itself about a second longer after I release the "Delete" key. This results in deleting 6-7 more characters than I intended to delete.

The same thing happens with the arrow keys. If I'm scrolling down through code with the arrow keys, the cursor overshoots by 6-7 lines after I've released the down arrow key.

The problem seems limited to the arrow keys, "delete", "home", "end", "pg up", "pd down".

I've noticed 2 things:

1. This problem **occurs when NumLock is ON** (when the extended keyboard numpad produces numbers). Turning off NumLock solves the problem. But I prefer using the numpad.
2. Strangely enough, not only does a USB keyboard work properly (no overshooting), but **it temporarily fixes the laptop's keyboard overshooting**. Once I've plugged a USB keyboard to my laptop, the overshooting problem stops occurring on my laptop's keyboard (even if NumLock is ON), whether the USB keyboard is plugged in or not. The problem however returns upon reboot of the system, or when I toggle NumLock OFF then ON again (whether the USB keyboard is plugged in or not).

Could this mean that the default keyboard driver on 20.04 is not up to date for all 2022 laptops, but once a USB keyboard driver is loaded, it somehow supersedes the default keyboard driver? I'm on kernel `5.15.0-46-generic`

EDIT: Playing with "Repeat keys" settings (delay and speed) does not solve the issue.

Comment: You provided very good detail. I cannot reproduce such issue on my setup.